# Visual Studio Error C2226 'unexpected type'

Tags: c, visual-c++

I have created a struct Data Type and trying to allocate memory dynamically for a list of those items, using `realloc` but it cause:

```
error C2226: syntax error : unexpected type 'Employee'
```

The [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k92azf0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) just say: A syntax error occurs before or in the type specifier.

I couldn't figure out what's wrong here.

```
int current_employees=0; 
struct Employee *list = 0;
```

...

```
current_employees++;
list =  struct Employee * realloc((void*) list, current_employees * sizeof(struct Employee));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably meant

```
list = (struct Employee *) realloc((void*) list, current_employees * sizeof(struct Employee));
```

Otherwise, you would be trying to multiply a type by a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Missing some parenthesis in that cast?

```
list =  (struct Employee *)realloc((void*) list, current_employees * sizeof(struct Employee));
```