# Error 3 error C2226: syntax error : unexpected type 'my_profile'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, syntax-error

## Problem

The following is part of the code snippet for my program:

### Code

```
computer_entry:
    {
        system("cls");
        system("color 4F");
        char m2;
        cout << "Profile: " << ob1.username << "\n\n" << "COMPUTER ENTRY: \n";
        cout << "\n1. Add new computer\n2. Show computer\n3. Update Record\n4. Delete Record\n5. Back\n";
        cin >> m2;
        switch (m2)
        {
        case '1':
        {
                    ob5.add_new_computer();
                    goto computer_entry;
                    break;
        }
        case '2':
        {
                    ob5.show_computer();
                    goto computer_entry;
                    break;
        }
        case '3':
        {
                    ob5.update();
                    goto computer_entry;
                    break;
        }
        case '4':
        {
                    ob5.del();
                    goto computer_entry;
                    break;
        }
        case '5':
        {
                    goto master_entry;
                    break;
        }
        default:
        {
                   goto computer_entry;
                   break;
        }
        }
    }
    if (ob5.trigger_computer_entry == 1)
    {
        ob5.trigger_computer_entry = 0;
        goto computer_entry;
    }


my_profile:
    {
        system("cls");
        system("color 01");
        cout << "Profile: " << ob1.username << "\n\n" << "MY PROFILE: \n";
        ob9.my_pro_file = ob1.my_file;
        ob9.my_profile_details();
        _getch();
        goto B;
    }

change_password:
    {
        system("cls");
        system("color 02");
        cout << "Profile: " << ob1.username << "\n\n" << "CHANGE PASSWORD: \n";
        ob10.change_user = ob1.change_pass;
        ob10.change_passcode();
        if (ob10.trigger_A == 1)
        {
            ob10.trigger_A = 0;
            goto A;
        }
        else if (ob10.trigger_B == 1)
        {
            ob10.trigger_B = 0;
            goto B;
        }
    }
```

The full code is found on this github repo: [Cyber-Cafe-management-IS-C ++-program](https://github.com/nk484/Cyber-Cafe-management-IS-program)

### Error Message

When one tries to build it up, it generates 16 similar errors as follows:

`Error  3 error C2226: syntax error : unexpected type 'my_profile'`
for the following:

- **my_profile**
- **member_entry**
- **computer_entry**
- **change_password**

Any help on how to solve and remove this error since there is no enough documentation on how to solve it in Microsoft Docs as found here: [Microsoft C2226 error Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2226?view=msvc-170).

I tried to check and use the help shown here: [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129060/visual-studio-error-c2226-unexpected-type) but it didn't work.

Comment: Please show a complete [mre] of the issue. These look like they are supposed to be labels, not types. But using labels and goto like this in C++ is highly unusual.

Comment: You can't reuse type names as labels.

Comment: Did molbdnilo's suggestion help you? I downloaded the code you uploaded and found two header files were missing. And in any programming language, the `goto` statement is not recommended. Because it makes the control flow of the program difficult to follow, it also makes the program difficult to understand and modify. Any program that uses the `goto` statement can be rewritten without the use of the `goto` statement.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

I have just solved it by removing the ambiguity of the names. I differentiated between the class names and those referred by the *goto* statement. This is shown below:

```
my_profile1:
{
    system("cls");
    system("color 01");
    cout << "Profile: " << ob1.username << "\n\n" << "MY PROFILE: \n";
    ob9.my_pro_file = ob1.my_file;
    ob9.my_profile_details();
    _getch();
    goto B;
}
```

While the ones in the class remained the same.